# Average of dates between many years

Tags: excel, date, average

I have a problem with calculation in Excel of average date (just need day and month) between dates of many years.

I tried this function:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(MONTH(D5:D56)=9;DATE(2010;9;DAY(D5:D56))))
```

Apparently, it just gave me average date of year 2010.

[image]

Please for any good advice.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your issue. What result do you expect? Can you work out the average manually and tell it to us?

Comment: An example of input with desired output would help.

Comment: Thank you for reply!
My goal is, to get average day and month (not interested in year!) between cell 34 and 56. For basic example: If we take 22.10. and 18.10. (year is not important) than the average date is 20.10. Anyway, I think represented formula is just for year 2010 and month 9 (sept.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this array formula do what you want?

```
=AVERAGE(DATE(2010,MONTH(D34:D56),DAY(D34:D56)))
```

Be sure to enter it using Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Comment: Please, see my first reply.

Comment: That makes sense.  Did you try the formula above?  I think it does what you want.  Just ignore the "2010" year that comes out.  You can use any year you want just to get Excel to produce a valid date.

Comment: Great! Formula successfully works! 
First I got some problems with input with formula in excel, but now works fine!
For year input, it does not matter which year you put it, result for day and mount is the same. 
Thank you. Have a nice week (: